# Geth Mismatch of the highestBlock while syncing

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization

While syncing on my Ubuntu 16.04 machine on ropsten yesterday the highestBlock matched the current highestBlock

```
> eth.syncing
{
  currentBlock: 2587196,
  **highestBlock: 3528808**,
  knownStates: 3685462,
  pulledStates: 3676041,
  startingBlock: 0
}
```

while I had to restart for some reason now when I again start it today I see this.

```
> eth.syncing
{
  currentBlock: 2785412,
  **highestBlock: 3113093**,
  knownStates: 4120516,
  pulledStates: 4113759,
  startingBlock: 2729984
}
```

The **highestBlock** has changed. Earlier it was showing the correct highestBlock but now it is showing the incorrect one. Is this normal and will the geth client correct itself on the way ?
The syncing is working normally.

```
System details
geth VERSION: 1.8.11-stable-dea1ce05
OS Ubuntu 16.04
```

Edit:
The synchronisation has stopped at this state and is now stagnant and not progressing.

```
> eth.syncing
{
  currentBlock: 3116323,
  highestBlock: 3116388,
  knownStates: 27269500,
  pulledStates: 27259299,
  startingBlock: 3116323
}
> eth.blockNumber
0
```

Is this issue somehow related with this github issue
https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/16202

Comment: Could I recommend parity, they have a light implementation that is quick to setup and i know it works because i run one everyday.

Comment: Yes that is also an option actually. I was researching about it. But I did not find anything similar to the `geth attach` IPC console in parity. If you could help me with it i would be grateful.

Comment: I've added an answer, let me know if you need further help. Also the question title doesn't match the answer, so if it is helpful consider re-titling to help future users.

Answer (score 0):

To start parity, if you already have chain data, you want it gone, run `parity --light db kill`.(don't worry, the new sync will download a good amount of the chain data and sync the rest)

Run `parity --light`. There is even a `--geth`flag to simulate a geth node if that is something you need.

For IPC with parity, there is a good comparative write up between parity and geth [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/17520/how-do-i-connect-ipc-with-parity)

Comment: @codestruggle. If it did, consider liking and accepting to add more visibility for future users.